# Tons of software disappeared after 20-04 dist-upgrade

Tags: 20.04, ffmpeg

I'm on 20.04, procrastinating on updating to 22.04 (older system, need to research performance implications first).

I kept getting "partial upgrade" messages, and wanted them to go away, so I just did an apt update + dist-upgrade.

This morning, I noticed a lot of software was missing. Gimp, Kdenlive, even ffmpeg!

When I try to reinstall ffmpeg, I get:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ffmpeg : Depends: libavcodec58 (= 7:4.4.3-0ubuntu1~20.04.sav3)
          Depends: libavdevice58 (= 7:4.4.3-0ubuntu1~20.04.sav3) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libavfilter7 (= 7:4.4.3-0ubuntu1~20.04.sav3)
          Depends: libavformat58 (= 7:4.4.3-0ubuntu1~20.04.sav3)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What gives? Why would an update delete things that I was clearly using? I guess dist-upgrade aggressively deletes dependencies that are still in use. Never again with that command haha.

How can I fix this? Do I basically just need to bite the bullet, let it upgrade to 22.04, and then manually reinstall all the software that got Thanos-snapped away from me?

ETA:

If I follow the trail of libraries, I eventually land on:

`E: Package 'libilbc3' has no installation candidate`

Comment: Not upgrade but a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04. An upgrade just carries the problems over.

Comment: Makes sense, I've been upgrading LTS distros on this thing since, I want to say, 14.04.

It would be nice if I could buy some time and figure out how to un-destroy my system.

If I follow the trail of libraries, I eventually land on: E: Package 'libilbc3' has no installation candidate

Comment: I made it an answer and you can accept it.

Comment: What gives: Mass removal of incompatible packages is exactly what a "partial upgrade" is offering. The system does not keep track of what you are using, nor knows your intent.

Comment: . Sorry I do not know why on the mass removal.

Comment: Got it. Lesson learned, will never run a dist-upgrade again when "partial upgrade" is being recommended, or will at least read the output EXTREMELY carefully to make sure mission critical apps don't get deleted from under me. This sets me back a lot.

Comment: Problem comes from this ppa https://launchpad.net/%7Esavoury1/+archive/ubuntu/ffmpeg4  i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a corrupted OS never just try and do an upgrade. Upgrades just carry any problems over. It is always best and maybe even faster to do a new fresh install of the the new OS.

Comment: Will accept this in a bit, but want to give time to others to answer, in case they have a solution that will allow me to buy some time and fix things later (I need my media software ASAP, but don't have time to muck around with a full install this week).

Comment: +1: A clean install is indeed the simplest and fastest way to restore a working system. The partial-upgrade has already occurred; that egg is already scrambled.

Comment: All this time I thought "partial upgrade" meant "if we tried upgrading all packages, you'd run into breaking issues due to stuff being deprecated/deleted, so we'll just upgrade the parts that can be upgraded without deleting dependencies that would break things you haven't asked us to delete." Maybe that's what it is, but I stupidly ran dist-upgrade, which doesn't give a "are you really really really sure because this will break things" error, aside from the usual big list of changes.

Comment: Linux lets you make your own mistakes and almost never questions you.